# Is there a way to use two locales simultaneously in an app?

Tags: android, android-resources

I would like to use two locales for resource values in an app.

For example, I want some specific strings to depend on what country the user is in right now (like phone numbers), while the rest of the strings will depend on the phone's language/locale settings.

Is there a clean way of doing this without programatically getting a string resource from a different locale? Or should I be using resources in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can set forcefully based on device locale and you will need to handle that pattern when locale check returns true for the particular locale. Also, check for a relevant pattern that needs to be set for example phone number.